# Disable default mapping convention for automapper

Tags: .net, automapper

HI,

I am using autommaper in my app and for now I have one problem. When I use ConstructUsing method for specify constructor to map object, after that Automapper copy all other fields by default convention. But I don't need that. How I can set, that Mapper should use JUST constructor without copy anything else? Or the only way is to write custom Converter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Ignore())` to avoid additional mapping. Only method call will be performed in this case.

Answer (score 2):

The converter is the way to go, it's designed to not do the other copying. It also takes a Func < TSource, TDestination > , so you should be able to just swap out the method you're calling in the configuration from ConstructUsing to ConvertUsing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want disable mapping for most of properties
you can use `.ForAllOtherMembers(opt => opt.Ignore())`